# Наложение цвета на background без учёта контента

Tags: html, css, изображения, background, color

Есть вот такой код:

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#first {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: url(https://www.anyway.website/d/first-section-background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

#first::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(83, 99, 219, .8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.first-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.trial-form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 390px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 100px 90px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 2;
}

.trial-form [type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: none;
  margin: 17px 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.trial-form h4 {
  margin-right: 100px;
  font-size: 25.6px;
  color: #5363db;
}

.trial-form .btn {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #5b6ceb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.trial-form input {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.heading {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.heading h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.heading h3 {
  font-family: FreeScrypt;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-content">
    <form action="" class="trial-form">
      <h4>Trial Class</h4>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone">
      <input type="text" name="dropdown" placeholder="Chose your class">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Try it</button>
    </form>
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Just Balance <br> your Mind & Body
      </h1>
      <h3>
        Create the healthy living <br> for yourself
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Суть вопроса - каким образом необходимо накладывать цвет на картинку так, чтобы контент не съезжал вниз ?

Answer (score 1):

UPD: Решил вопрос сам, через псевдоэлемент before, добавил ему z-index: 1; Остальным элементам в секции присвоил z-index: 2;

Убрал блок "overlay"